# How to remove strings from a string based on the contents of a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Checks if something contains any instance of any element in myString. Something may be "Sideboard: 1 Forest", "SB: 1 Mountain", "SB 1 Plains", etc. If something does contain any of the elements of the array, those elements will always be followed by a white space, a number, a white space, and a string: " 1 Swamp".

```
string[] myString = {"Side", "side", "Board", "board", "Sideboard", "sideboard", "SB", "sb", "SB:", "sb:"};

if(myString.Any(s => something.Contains(s)))
{
    // newSomething = something but with any instance of any element in myString removed
    // from the start of something up to the first whitespace.
}
```

I need help with the removing part of the comment in the above if statement block.

### EDIT

Those are some blunt responses, but I understand!

I did go through the introduction and tried to searched for relevant stuff but couldn't find this situation. This is a little program I made for personal use, not for an assignment. I do not know anything about regular expressions.

As for clarification, at the point in the program where "something" is found to contain any of the elements in the "myString" array, I then want to remove those elements only from the start of the string in "something".

Ex: something = "Sideboard: 1 Inside Out"

I want to remove "myString" elements only from the beginning of the string and before the number because the strings after the number may also contain elements of "myString".

Also, upon submitting this question, I instantly figured out a way to do the removing: I just used TrimStart() with an array containing the individual characters of the elements in "myString". This did what I wanted but I kept this question up to look for a more elegant solution. So, for all intents and purposes, this question is already answered.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use regular expression for this task.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I would suggest reading [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com), the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and/or [How to ask a question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov: I'm willing to bet this is homework, and as such, they probably haven't covered regex yet. Not saying you're wrong, or that they shouldn't look into it, but it's probably not what the instructor is looking for if it is indeed homework.

Comment: question is very difficult to understand, please clarify and give examples where possible

Comment: In this case you should write restrictions to technologies that is available to use. But i suppose that you should do your homework yourself.

Comment: I don't know if you guys get an indication when a question is edited, so I will post a comment. I assume posting a comment will give you an indication of activity in a question like most sites.

I edited the question and added clarifications and answers to these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string newSomething = something.Substring(0, something.IndexOf(' '));
```

The above code will return a string ending at the first instance of a space in the 'something' string. If there are no spaces in the 'something' string, there will be an exception.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, good luck.

Comment: The use of "ending at" confuses me a little. So, say the string of something is "Side: 1 Island", newSomething will then be "Side:" or "Side: "? In either case, that does help and I then just need to remove that string from something and then trim the white space, which I know.

Thanks!

Comment: The something.indexOf(' ') is where the string ends. You can +1 or -1 right after the closing bracket to move the position to the right or left.